# How can I access https file via https request without 403 forbidden in IIS?

Tags: redirects, https, iis

I recently installed a site certificate to secure our website.  We sell software and there are many installed users who are using some pre-website change versions of our software.  Internally, the software checks a text file on the server to parse certain information to see if a newer version exists.

Specifically it tries to download a file with this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/updates/latestversion.txt
```

That is, of course, now failing with 403 forbidden, so those users have no way of knowing if an update is available unless they visit the site.

I have tried setting up a URL Rewrite Inbound rule in IIS Manager, but I'm not having any luck with this.  I am not an expert at this.

What I would like to do is have

```
http://www.example.com/updates/latestversion.txt
```

be redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/updates/latestversion.txt
```

`http://www.example.com/` gets redirected automatically to
`https://www.example.com` so I feel there must be a way to have the text file request redirected as well.

Any help here would be much appreciated, I'm out of my element here.

Comment: "That is, of course, now failing with 403 forbidden" - Why "of course"? If you had simply installed an SSL cert then you wouldn't _expect_ the HTTP request to be blocked with a 403? If you implement a "redirect" then the software making this request must also be configured to follow this redirect (would it?). However, it would be preferable to change the software so that it requests HTTPS. You also can't "URL rewrite" across protocols - you would need to configure a reverse proxy to do this.

Comment: "`http://www.example.com/` gets redirected automatically to `https://www.example.com` so I feel there must be a way to have the text file request redirected as well." - The "quick fix" would seemingly be to redirect everything, but make _exceptions_, for these software-update checks. However, you would need to resolve where those 403s are coming from?

Comment: "`http://www.example.com/` gets redirected automatically..." - I would also query how this is happening seemingly "automatically".

Comment: I beleve something I changed in plesk control panel "automatically" makes that happen :-)  As to changing the software, that defeats the entire purpose.  I want users with their version to be able to be alerted (through the software) that an update is available, otherwise I just let them alone or send our a few thousand emails.

Comment: Do you get a 403 error when accessing it directly from your browser, or just from your software package?

Comment: Actually, get it from browser when typing in http: instead of https:  The software gets it because http:// url is hardcoded in the software.